# How to use, useMemo Hook, from React to sort Items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, jsx

This problem occurs when I want to "sort" users from an array of objects, within an HTML table, only via the onClick handleSort on the columns of the latter. For example, if I click on ID, it will sort the IDs, if I click on username for the usernames, etc.
I wanted to do all this using the useMemo function. And so far this is what I've managed to create:

My StaffData.js:

```
const StaffDati = ({utentiLista, staffColumns}) => {
    
    const sortedUtentiLista = useMemo(() => {
  
      const utenti = [...utentiLista];
      const sortColumn = [...staffColumns].find(
        (column) => column.isSortable
      )
      if (sortColumn) {
        utenti.sort((a, b) => {
          if(typeof sortColumn.type === 'number'){
          
          }else{
            
          }
        });
      }
  
      return utenti;
    }, [utentiLista, staffColumns]);

  const styleText = {
    backgroundColor: '#1F2A37',
    textAlign: 'left',
    padding:'10px 10px 10px 10px',
    color: 'var(--primary-text)',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    borderTop: '1px solid #343E4E',
    borderBottom: '1px solid #343E4E',
  }


    const getStatusStyle = (status) => {
        switch (status) {
          case 'Completed':
            return ({ color: 'lightgreen',
                      src: check
            });
          case 'Pending':
            return { color: 'yellow',
                      src: hour
          };
          case 'In progress':
            return { color: '#A992F6',
                      src: cloud
          };
          default:
            return {};
        }
      };
    return (
        <tbody style={{width:'100%'}}>
      {
      
      sortedUtentiLista.map((utente, index) => (
        
      <tr key={utente.id} style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <td style={{...styleText, borderLeft: index === -1  ? 'none' : '1px solid #343E4E'}}>{utente.id}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.username}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.data}</td>
        <td style={styleText}>{utente.amount}€</td>
        <td style={{...styleText, borderRight: index === utentiLista.length  ? 'none' : '1px solid #343E4E' }}>

          <div style={{color: getStatusStyle(utente.status).color, 
                       width: 'fit-content', 
                       padding:'5px', 
                       border:`1px solid ${getStatusStyle(utente.status).color}`, 
                       borderRadius: '10px', 
                       fontSize: '10px',
                       backgroundColor: '#374151',
                       display: 'flex',
                       flexDirection: 'row', 
                       flexWrap: 'no-wrap',
                       alignContent: 'center', 
                       gap: '5px'}}>
                        <img src={getStatusStyle(utente.status).src} alt="" />
          {utente.status}
          </div>
          </td>
      
      </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
    )
    
}

export default StaffDati;
```

My StaffColumn.js:

```
const ColoneStaff = ({staffColumns, setStaffColumns}) => {
    
    const styleTr = {
        backgroundColor: '#374151',
        color: 'var(--primary-text)',
        textAlign: 'left',
      }

    const handleSort = (field) => {
      const updatedColumns = staffColumns.map((column) => {
        if (column.field === field) {
         !column.isSortable ? column.isSortable = true : column.isSortable = false;
        }
        return column;
      });
      setStaffColumns(updatedColumns);
    };
    return (
        <thead>
 <tr style={{...styleTr}}>

        {staffColumns.map((column) =>  {
            return(
             <th key={column.field} onClick={() =>handleSort(column.field)} style={column.style}>
             {column.name}
            </th>  
            )
        })
    }
   
     </tr>
    </thead>
    );
}

export default ColoneStaff;
```

And this is my Tabella.js, which acts like the parent components of the body and head of the Table:

```
const Tabella = ({utentiLista, setUtentiLista}) => {
 const styleTh = {
   backgroundColor: '#374151',
   color: 'var(--primary-text)',
   textAlign: 'left',
   padding: '20px 0px 20px 10px',
   cursor: 'pointer',
 };
 const [staffColumns, setStaffColumns] = useState([
   {
   name: 'ID',
   field: 'id',
   type: 'number',
   style: styleTh,
   isSortable: false,
 },
 {
     name: 'Username',
     field: 'username',
     type: 'string',
     style: styleTh,
     isSortable: false,
 },
 {
     name: 'Data',
     field: 'data',
     type: 'string',
     style: styleTh,
     isSortable: false,
 },
 {
     name: 'Amount',
     field: 'amount',
     type: 'number',
     style: styleTh,
     isSortable: false,
 },
 {
     name: 'Status',
     field: 'status',
     type: 'string',
     style: styleTh,
     isSortable: false,
 },
 
]);

 const styleTable = {
   width: '95%',
   textAlign: 'center',
   borderRadius: '10px',
   overflow: 'hidden',
   borderCollapse: 'collapse',
   borderSpacing: '0 0px',
 }

 

 
  return (
   <table className="table" style={styleTable}>
   <ColonneStaff staffColumns={staffColumns} setStaffColumns={setStaffColumns}/>
   <StaffDati utentiLista={utentiLista} staffColumns={staffColumns}/>
 </table>
);
}

export default Tabella;
```

My list of utent it's being stored, and passed as a props to the Tabella.js
This is my list of utents:

```
const [utentiLista, setUtentiLista] = useState([
    {id: 1, username: 'FEDERICOSCHI', data: '...', amount: 2000, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 2, username: 'Feryzz', data: '...', amount: 15, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 3, username: 'Cinquanta', data: '...', amount: 27, status: 'Pending'},
    {id: 4, username: 'NotAffected', data: '...', amount: 50, status: 'In progress'},
    {id: 5, username: 'Ytnoos', data: '...', amount: 12, status: 'Completed'},
    {id: 6, username: 'Mattia882', data: '...', amount: 33, status: 'In progress'}
  ]);
```

Now my problem is on that useMemo on StaffDati and it's really driving me crazy, the sorting doesn't work so well. Any suggestion??